# Multi user - Drag&Drop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a tree ful with data that are draggable (& droppable). It all works fine, but there's one problem. When more users're working on this module (with tree) and they're dragging objects around, all get mixed up. So I'm working on a solution, but I got as far as table lock in mysql. But if I do that, just one user can work on this module and that is no acceptable.

Got any ideas?

Comment: What behaviour do you want instead of a one-user-at-a-time lock: to see each other changes in real time, during their edit sessions? Or, a three-way (or N-way) merge of all users changes at the end of each of their editing sessions?

Comment: Real time is one option, but there is still open window of error.
Maybe there isn't any more options. Thank you for your comment. I think I'll do this the old fashion way (locking table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about when a user clicks on the object a request is sent to the MySQL database requesting approval for that user to move that object.

If that object is not tagged as being moved then the database returns true and the javascript makes the object draggable. MySQL marks that row in the table with one of the fields (i.e. you create a field called locked and set it to true or false)

If the MYSQL returned false then the user would get some sort of notification that someone else was moving that object currently.

I would also create a timestamp each time a row is marked as locked so you can check if the object has been unlocked)

good luck,

Niko

Comment: I got to this solution by now. So thank you any way! It is the most elegant solution. I created a lock on parent of tree.